# How to expand keyval options immediately

Tags: expansion, strings, key-value

I am trying to build up a macro that creates other macros depending on `kvoptions`' options. But then, the outcoming macros are dependent on the actual state of the options instead of their state at the runtime of the creation macro.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kvoptions}

\makeatletter
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family = fam, prefix = fam@}
\DeclareStringOption[]{prename}

\newcommand{\greetingsetup}[3]{%
        \setkeys{fam}{#3}
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname greeting#1\endcsname{Hallo \fam@prename, I am #2.}
}

\makeatother
\greetingsetup{john}{Johnny}{prename=Mike}
\greetingsetup{mark}{Mark}{prename=Michaela}

\begin{document}

\greetingjohn


\end{document}
```

**What I want**:
Writing `\greetingsetup{john}{Johnny}{prename=Mike}` creates a macro `\greetingjohn` which writes "Hallo Mike, I am Johnny."

**What it does**: It creates a macro `\greetingjohn` which writes "Hallo xyz, I am Johnny." with xyz being replaced with the actual state of option prename. In the example LaTeX writes "Hallo Michaela, I am Johnny.".

Does anyone know how I can get just the bare *string* from the option `\fam@prename` written to the new macro `\greeting`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the expansion using `\edef` or its safer LaTeX wrapper `\protected@edef`:

```
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname greeting#1\endcsname{Hallo \fam@prename, I am #2.}
```

Comment: Yes!! Brilliant!
Thank you very much, David! :-)

(Also thank you Svend Mortensen for polishing the format of my question)